# How to delete an old iCloud account from an iPhone if the Apple ID has been deleted

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

I deleted my old Apple ID but forgot to log out from iCloud. I now can't reset my phone without turning off Find my iPhone because you need to sign in to iCloud to turn it off. I asked Apple Support to restore the account, but they say they can't.

Answer (score 1):

This article looks like it may be your answer.
It details how to deactivate your old AppleID in particular.
You could also, if I understand your problem, put your AppleID back on the iPhone, turn off Find my phone, then again delete the appleID.
Or check this link for ways to do it without having your iPhone set up again.

https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/how-to-delete-or-deactivate-your-apple-id-account/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.